# get id of button in button handler javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm updating a page through ajax, so I'm creating (text) buttons dynamically.  I know how to set up an onclick event, but then how to I get the id of the button in the handler?

Using sinatra with ruby and jquery 1.5.
Here is the partial code:

```
<div onclick='my_handler()' ><a><href>[Edit]</href></a></div>
```

and the js code:

```
function my_handler (){
   alert ("button id is ..." )
}
```

thanks

Comment: What button? I don't see any button elements in your example.

Comment: And you should brush up on your html. `href` isn't a tag, and your `div` doesn't have an `id` parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
alert ("button id is " + this.id);
```

And since you've said you're already using jQuery, please separate your HTML and JS:

```
<div class="edit">
```

and

```
$('div.edit').on('click', function()
{
    alert ("button id is " + this.id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but I'm not explaining correctly.  The above solution works once, but when I reload the form, using AJAX, it no longer works.  That's why I was adding the 'onclick' attribute dynamically.  The 'onclick' solution works after reloads, I just don't know how to get the id.   Does that make sense?  My terminology may be wrong, here, I'm a newbie.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The `.on()` solution will work even if you dynamically build the HTML.